# How to make multiple user mobile number authentication using OTP in iOS using Twitter Digit Framework?

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter-fabric, twitter-digits

Hello guys i am using  i am using Objective-C, Parse and Twitters-Digits  framework in my app in a users session app will allow to take 1 userid for single mobile number verification...i am saving it into Parse's current user's User Class with this details. when i login with an account app will allow to me for mobile verification using OTP but when i am logout and login with another account then app will take existing user id(Mobile no) which i stored in iPhone's keychain how to handled condition when i login with multiple accounts to take multiple condition my code is below:

```
- (void)verifyPhone:(id)sender {

    [[Digits sharedInstance] authenticateWithCompletion:^(DGTSession *session, NSError *error) {
        // Inspect session/error objects

        if (session.userID) {
            // TODO: associate the session userID with your user model

            PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
            [user setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"mobileverify"];
            [user saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                if (succeeded) {


                    NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Phone number: %@", session.phoneNumber];

                    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"You are logged in!" message:msg preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

                    UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction
                                               actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"OK action")
                                               style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                               handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                                               {
                                                   NSLog(@"Mobile Verification Status Saved Sucessfully.");

                                                   [verifyPhoneButton setTitle:@"Phone Verified" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                                                   [verifyPhoneButton setEnabled:NO];
                                                   [verifyPhoneButton setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

                                               }];

                    [alertController addAction:okAction];
                    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];


                }
                else {

                    NSLog(@"Error ==%@", error);
                }
            }];


        } else if (error) {

            NSLog(@"Authentication error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
        }


    }];    
}
```

Comment: @ZeMoon thanks for editing...i have not got details in digits doc just searching for solution

Answer (score 0):

i got the solution from apple docs for Twitter-Digits Frameworks

https://docs.fabric.io/appledocs/Digits/Classes/Digits.html

i just have to end up the Session at the time of logout with following line :

```
[[Digits sharedInstance] logOut];
```